# Search directory and sub-directories for pattern in a file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

In linux, I want to search the given directoy and its sub-folders/files for certain include and exclude pattern.

```
find /apps -exec grep "performance" -v "warn" {} /dev/null \;
```

This echoes loads of lines from which search goes trough. I don't want that, I'd like to find files containing performance which do not contain warn. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very close to what you have already:

```
find /apps -exec grep "performance" {} /dev/null \; | grep -v "warn"
```

Just pipe the output through a second call to `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

To find files containing `performance` but not `warn`, list the files containing `performance`, then filter out the ones that contain `warn`. You need separate calls to `grep` for each filter. Use the `-l` option to grep so that it only prints out file names and not matching lines. Use `xargs` to pass the file names from the first pass to the command line of the second-pass `grep`.

```
find /apps -type f -exec grep -l "performance" /dev/null {} + | 
sed 's/[[:blank:]\"'\'']/\\&/g' |
xargs grep -lv "warn"
```

(The `sed` call in the middle is there because `xargs` expects a weirdly quoted input format that doesn't correspond to what any other command produces.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `-exec` option of the `find` command is less effective than pipelining  it to `xargs`:

```
find /apps -print0 | xargs -0 grep -n -v "warn" | grep "performance"
```

This, probably, also solves your problem with printing unwanted output. You will also probably want tu use the `-name` option to filter out specific files.

```
find /apps -name '*.ext' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -n -v "warn" | grep "performance"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find files that do not contain "warn" at all, `grep -v` is not what you want -- that prints all lines not containing "warn" but it will not tell you that the file (as a whole) does not contain "warn"

```
find /apps -type f -print0 | while read -r -d '' f; do
    grep -q performance "$f" && ! grep -q warn "$f" && echo "$f"
done
```