# Search directory for unique path and patterns

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search a directory structure, and files for all instances of where a pattern exists. Than I want that file location recorded in a log file that I can review latter. I looked at various posts, but I have not found a similar example where this is happening. Reviewed posts include:

1. [PowerShell Scripting - Get-ChildItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370210/powershell-scripting-get-childitem)
2. [Search List for unique pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592737/search-list-for-unique-pattern)
3. [Search directory and sub-directories for pattern in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225922/search-directory-and-sub-directories-for-pattern-in-a-file)
4. [Use an Easy PowerShell Command to Search Files for Information](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/04/use-an-easy-powershell-command-to-search-files-for-information/)
5. [Get full path of the files in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126175/get-full-path-of-the-files-in-powershell)

Here is the code I am using to recuse through the folder structure:

```
#Set variables for paths
$Results = "C:\Results"
$Source = "C:\Test\*"
$Destination = "C:\MyTest\"

#Create file name for each report with date and time of run
$ReportDate = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")

$CustomPattern = Read-Host 'What pattern are you looing for?'
$CustomPatternLog = New-Item -itemType File -Path C:\Results -Name $("CustomerPattern_" + $ReportDate + ".txt")
$CustomPattern = foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Recurse | Select-String -pattern $CustomPattern | Select-Object -Unique Path) {$file.path}
$CustomPattern > "$($Results)\$($CustomPatternLog)"
```

However, this code is returning the following error:

> Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
>   The fully  qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and
>   the directory name  must be less than 248 characters. At line:19
>   char:36
>   + $CustomPattern = foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Recurse  | S ...
>   +                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Test\Mor...ofiles\Customer:St     ring) [Get-ChildItem],
>   PathTooLongException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChil     dItemCommand

Do you have a better way to do the same operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this

```
$CustomPatternLog = New-Item -itemType File -Path C:\Results -Name $("CustomerPattern_" + $ReportDate + ".txt")
$CustomPattern = foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Recurse | Select-String -pattern $CustomPattern | Select-Object -Unique Path) {$file.path}
$CustomPattern > "$($Results)\$($CustomPatternLog)"
```

with this

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Recurse

#in case you would need the path replace FullName with PsParentPath
$result = ($files | ?{$_.name -like "*$CustomPattern*"}).FullName 
$result | out-file ($CustomPattern + "_" + $ReportDate + ".txt")
```

and since its shell you can do the same with one liner

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Recurse | ?{$_.name -like "*$CustomPattern*"}).FullName | out-file ($CustomPattern + "_" + $ReportDate + ".txt")
```

Comment: I am using the suggested code, but logs are completely empty. I am searching for the word 'false' with plenty of files with that word, but no results reported back.  Any idea?

Comment: tested it again and the both codes are working for me. Can you share your code and the output of cmdlet Get-ChildItem?

Comment: I figured out the problem. $Destination was set to C:\MyTest and once I changed it to C:\MyTest\*.* all my errors went away with your code.  Thank you so very much for your help and updated code suggestion.

Comment: huh, it should not be that reason. Path can be set as a simple path without wildcards. The wildcard is replaced by `-recurse`. Did again a test just to be sure.